# How to group list of objects c#

Tags: c#

I am calling several API's so I have a problem to group received data

For example:

1. Api 1 is returning a list of objects and each object have different buildingId.
2. That buildingId I need to use as an input for Api 2 which is returning list of objects (apartments) where each of the apartment have different apartmentId.
3. Then I have to call Api 3 and use apartmentId as an input and I will receive a list of owner/s of the apartment.

Final result should be like

```
BuildingA
   Apartment1
      ApartmentOwner1
      ApartmentOwner2
   Apartment2
      ApartmentOwner3
   Apartment3
      ApartmentOwner4
      ApartmentOwner5
      ApartmentOwner6
BuildingB
   Apartment1
      ApartmentOwner1
      ApartmentOwner2
   Apartment2
      ApartmentOwner3
      ApartmentOwner4
```

I have created model for all 3 types of objects, this is example for Building.

```
public class BuildingResponse
    {
        public int BuildingId { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
 }
```

I understand that I have to use foreach over data returned by Api 1 (over buildings), but how to achieve the rest of the requirement?

Thanks

Comment: So, every building will have some List<Apartment> and in every Apartmen you will also need some list of owners, just add that lists in your models. After that u can go troguht lists and take whatever you need.

Comment: You should have three lists 1) List<BuildingResponse> 2) List<ApartmentResponse> 3) List<OwnerResponse>   Then you can use a do a query to Join (or use Where) to linkkeke the three lists together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control of the API, and you know you need your building objects to be fully populated, and your apartment objects to be fully populated, you could expose an endpoint that returns fully populated buildings. That is, buildings with their apartments populated and apartments with their owners populated.

If not, one approach would be to add something like a `List<ApartmentResponse>` to the `BuildingResponse` model, and something like a `List<ApartmentOwnerResponse>` to the `ApartmentResponse` model.

Then, you iterate through the `BuildingResponse` models you get back from your API and request the `ApartmentResponse` models for that building and store it in the `List<ApartmentResponse>` you add to the `BuildingResponse` model.

Then iterate through the `ApartmentResponse` models, request the `ApartmentOwnerResponse` models from the API, and add them to the `List<ApartmentOwnerResponse>` you add to the `ApartmentResponse` model.

For example...

```
public class BuildingResponse
{
    // Other properties / methods
    public List<ApartmentResponse> Apartments { get; private set; } = new List<ApartmentResponse>();
}

public class ApartmentResponse
{
    // Other properties / methods
    public List<ApartmentOwnerResponse> Owners { get; private set; } = new List<ApartmentOwnerResponse>();
}

public class ApartmentOwnerResponse
{
    // Properties / methods
}

public List<BuildingResponse> GetBuildings()
{
    List<BuildingResponse> buildings = GetBuildingsFromApi();
    foreach (BuildingResponse building in buildings)
    {
        List<ApartmentResponse> apartments = GetBuildingApartmentsFromApi(building.BuildingId);
        building.Apartments.AddRange(apartments);
        foreach (ApartmentResponse apartment in apartments)
        {
            List<ApartmentOwnerResponse> owners = GetApartmentOwnersFromApi(apartment.ApartmentId);
            apartment.Owners.AddRange(owners);
        }
    }
    return buildings;
}
```

You should be aware that this is a N+1 problem, where you're executing one request against the API to get all the parents (`BuildingResponse`) then for each of those you're executing another request to get the children (`ApartmentResponse`). Then you're doing it again for `ApartmentResponse` and `ApartmentOwnerResponse`. This could be a performance problem, especially as your list of buildings and apartments grow.